# Link multiple xib to one controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Ive been searching for the answer to this, but nothing yet.

I am trying to work around an issue were I have a view that resizes automatically.  If 3GS, etc... it uses picture.png, if iphone 4 & 5 it uses picture@2x.png.

However when the resize happens, the background on iphone 4 stretches below the bottom border, so part of the background is covered.

on the iphone 5 it fits perfectly, but the buttons dont adjust, they stay in place like if the screen was from a 3G (same thing if the iphone 4 is the simulator).

If you have a solution for the above issue, I am all ears, I am very new to xcode, and I'm just trying to learn.

As a work around I was thinking about checking for screensize, and then loading a xib built for that screen, however my app crashes with the following code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;

CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

if (screenHeight == 568){
    nibNameOrNil = (NSString*)@"main5";
     self = [self initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }

}else{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
}

}
return self;
```

Thank you in advanced

debug

self    Mainscreencantroller *  0x00000000
nibNameOrNil    NSString *  0x02a01196
NSObject    NSObject
isa Class   0x656a626f
[0] Class
nibBundleOrNil  __NSArrayM *    0x0a55d3e0

Comment: You call [self initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nil];. This should probably be super

Comment: The proper solution is to learn about the new layout constraint system for managing view sizes and positions. You shouldn't need to have two different xib files. Also, the screen size on the iPhone 4 is the same as 3 not 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after fiddling for a while, I decided to approach by controlling the Grect bounds.

Below is the code,

However I am still interested in knowing if you can load multiple xibs into a controller

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

{

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    NSLog(@"screenheight =%f", screenHeight);
    if(screenHeight == 568){

        screenBound.origin.y = -44;
        self.view.bounds = screenBound;

    }else if (screenHeight ==480){
        self.view.bounds = screenBound;
    }
        // Custom initialization
}
```

return self;